# How to access the array values obtained through AJAX response after using JSON.parse(data)?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, ajax

I passed the `array` (this array is obtained from the database) from PHP to JS as a response to my ajax request from JS.

So my question is : 
**How do I access the values of the `array` that I sent through AJAX from PHP inside JS?**

PHP code:

```py
while($temp = @mysqli_fetch_array($execute_query)){
    $items_list[] = $temp['item_name'];
  }
}
echo (json_encode($items_list));
```

PHP output:

> ["100% Whole Wheat Bread", "Almond Biscotti", "Almond Cake"]

JS code(used jQuery):

```py
var items_name_list = [];
$.ajax({
          url : 'get_items_list.php',
          datatype : 'json',
          success : (data)=> {
            items_name_list.push(JSON.parse(data));
          },
          error : (e) => {console.log(e);}
        });
```

JS output(on console):

> []
>   0: (166) ["100% Whole Wheat Bread", "Almond Biscotti", "Almond Cake"]
>   length: 1
>   **proto**: Array(0)

How do I access the value `Almond Biscotti` that is present inside the `array 
0`:

> (166) ["100% Whole Wheat Bread", "Almond Biscotti", "Almond Cake Specials"]**

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: Where do you want to access that data? In JS? What have you tried so far, where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Yes in JS. forEach(), Object.key(obj), Object.entries(obj).

Comment: I converted the string to object with JSON.parse()    But I'm unable to access individual values of the array even after JSON.parse()

Comment: You're adding an array in an array using `items_name_list.push(JSON.parse(data))`. you should use `items_name_list.concat(JSON.parse(data))`

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue Thanks a lot the problem's solved.